Azure Synapse to Update , Insert or Delete data from cosmos to Data Lake on existing csv file and maintain Transactional data with append
Below is the Json object which I have pushed from cosmos to data lake through azure synapse dataflow pipeline. Now if any changes in below data it must overwrite the data in the existing csv file which is present in data lake and if there is no  transactional file , it should create new transaction file and continue to append the changes.
I wanted to create pipeline to address above query as I am new boy to this azure cloud platform
Sample Json-
    {
    "timeFrames": [
        {
            "yearGroup": "Reception",
            "term": "Summer",
            "scoreIndeces": {
                "66": 0.2,
                "67": 0.3
            }
        },
        {
            "yearGroup": "Year 1",
            "term": "Spring",
            "scoreIndeces": {
                "64": 0.6,
                "65": 0.6
            }
        }
    ],
    "tableType": 1,
    "id": "f82",
    "productId": "4b",
    "productName": "New PUMA"
}

Transactions

Main


what do you mean by transactional file?

Hello @PratikLad,
I need to track the modifications done on main csv file  like insert ,update or delete.

can you add format of sample data you need in transactional file.

Hi @PratikLad,
I have attached files for references.

if any changes happen in cosmos it should updated in main file and in transactional file is my understanding correct?

In main file it should overwrite if any update , insert if new record and delete .
In transactional files it should keep updating the changes details as mentioned in the file

it should be based on Cosmos DB changes correct?

Exactly!! @PratikLad

To achieve your requirement, you need to first copy the data from main file to Transection file with adding additional column to it and custom value as inserted so we get the initial transections.

Then using data flow compare these files whenever Changes happens in new file as below:

Take dataflow activity add new dataflow to it. Create two sources first using transection file and second using main file.

After secon source take exist transformantion and add  Left stream as source 2, Right stream as source 1, Exist type  as Doesn't exist, Exists conditions as all columns from source are equal.



This will return you a updated  rows the take dericed column transformation and create column with same name as transection file Transaction Type and assigne Update value to it.



Then after first source take union transformation and add derived column transformation and source 1 as incoming streams as below:



This will return you required output and store it in transection file.



Note:- When Synapse pipeline write data to ADLS gen 2 files it will only overwrite data do not append it. so better way to handle your situation is to RDMS database like SQL

